# Start my soul-bolts

Tags: expressions

> "start my soul-bolts"

(Melville, White Jacket) - an expletive by a 19th-century sailor. Rather specific, but maybe somebody can come up with an equivalent. (Where's the 'nautical' S.E. site, anyway?)

Comment: Some context is needed.

Comment: About to arrive home the speaker vows to stay ashore for the rest of his life. The expletive is similar to 'I'll eat my hat, if..." or rather "you bet!"

Comment: Your *soul bolts* are those (metaphorical) thing that fasten your soul to your body. If you were to remove them or rip them out, your immortal soul would flee your body... aka you would die. He’s saying “if I’m lying, let God kill me here and now”. *Start*, I don’t know.. get moving, get initially loosened, somehow make more likely they’ll come free. Side note: there was a kind of punishment aboard ship involving being whipped by a special rope.. that rope was sometimes known as a *starter* (as in *starting* a horse with a whip), a *teaser*, or a *toagy*.

Comment: *Start* also means to jump with surprise (*be startled*); in an old wooden ship the twisting of the timbers in a heavy sea always brought the risk that a bolt would spring out, and often that was noisy and frightening.

Comment: I'd translate 'start' simply as 'break loose' or 'unfasten' and the expression as 'strike me dead, if...' (I ever set foot on a plank again).

Comment: @A.Berg That is correct

Comment: What are you asking? For somebody to explain what the term means—or for an alternative expression? If you're looking for an alternative expression, explain what *you* think the term means.

Comment: @A.Berg Yes, as in [... and then it was that we discovered that they had belonged to a French schooner, in the same trade, which had started a plank, and had gone down like a shot, ...](https://books.google.com/books?id=6nt9DoN7724C&pg=PA289&lpg=PA289&dq=%22started+a+plank%22&source=bl&ots=d__-I9Hf9R&sig=wCnrlPsDjUvpEYBteedPaVUWC7I&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjNu72w87TfAhVHhOAKHU6IDSAQ6AEwB3oECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22started%20a%20plank%22&f=false)

Comment: And [he embarked, was suddenly attacked by some monstrous fish, probably a thorn-back whale, who gave it such a terrible stroke with his tail as started a plank.](https://books.google.com/books?id=t3JDAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA309&lpg=PA309&dq=%22started+a+plank%22&source=bl&ots=pSlBuXB_I1&sig=Orqs_Wwad23ttHFRI5M69ZEieHA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjNu72w87TfAhVHhOAKHU6IDSAQ6AEwCHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22started%20a%20plank%22&f=false)

Comment: Robert Louis Stevenson deployed "[shiver my soul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiver_my_timbers)" a few years later in *Treasure Island*